# Active questions page is empty

Tags: bug

When I look at the "active questions" page, I get an empty list of questions (the "number of question" on the side also displays $0$). That's true for both the main site and the meta. Is this happening only to me or to other people too? And why is this happening?

**Edit $1$:** This happens not only for the "active questions" page, but also for "newest", "unanswered", etc.

**Edit $2$:** Now everything is back to normal. I'd like to know what happened, though.

Comment: I have the same issue for the "active" and "votes" tabs only (I'm running Firefox 26.0 on Windows 8).